# what is the best way for search in json file in php?

Tags: php, function, recursion

hi i have many data files in json format in a folder.
now i want to search a filed in them .my search word maybe not exist in some of them and may be exist in one of them files.
i have read this function and if not exits in a file i call the function to read another file.
when i echo the result show me and works fine but return not working and no data returned.

```
    function get_shenavari_in_files($search,$type)
{
    static $counter =1 ;
    $darsadi = 0;
    $find = false;
    
    $file_name = get_files_in_dir(); // make an array of file names
    $file_number = count($file_name)-$counter ;
    $file="files/" .$file_name[$file_number];
    $file_data   = read_json($file);

    for($i = 0 ; $i<count($file_data) ; $i++)
    {
        if($file_data[$i][$type] == $search )
        {
            $darsadi = $file_data[$i]['darsadi'] ;
            $find = true;
            echo $darsadi ; //this works and show the data 
            return $darsadi; // this is my problem no data return.
            break;              
        }
    }
    if($find == false)
    {   
        $counter ++;
        get_shenavari_in_files($search,$type);
    }

}

var_dump(get_shenavari_in_files('Euro','symbol')); //return null
```

Comment: Later in your code you call `get_shenavari_in_files`, as this doesn't return the value it won't be passed back.

Answer (score 0):

Once you recurse into `get_shenavari_in_files`, any found value is never returned back to the inital caller, i.e. instead of

```
if($find == false)
{   
    ...
    get_shenavari_in_files($search,$type);
}
```

you simply need to prepend the function call with a `return`statement

```
if($find == false)
{   
    ...
    return get_shenavari_in_files($search,$type);
}
```

Having said that, I would try a much simpler (and thereby less error-prone) approach, e.g.:

```
function get_shenavari_in_files($search, $type) {

    $files   = glob("files/*.json"); // Get names of all JSON files in a given path 
    $matches = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) { 

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true); 

        foreach ($data as $row) {

            if (array_key_exists($type, $row) && $row[$type] == $search) {

                $matches[$file] = $search;
            }

        }
    }

    return $matches;
}
```

This way, you would be able to eliminate the need for a recursive call to `get_shenavari_in_files`. Also, the function itself would become more performant because it doesn't have to scan the file system over and over again.